# Simple document creation failing with mongoengine module in Python with AttributeError:_initialised

Tags: python, attributeerror, mongoengine

I am trying to create very simple document in my mongo DB using mongoengine as a first step.
I am getting AttributeError: _initialised

Below is my code :

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

def createConnection():
    conn_str = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    connect(host=conn_str)

class Student(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'student_db', 'allow_inheritance': True}
    stdName = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.stdName = name 

if __name == '__main__':
    createConnection()
    s1 = Student('Phil')
    s1.save()
```

I am getting below error to execute the code :

```
File "<path to mongoengine\base\document.py", line 201 , in __setattr__
  super().__setattr__(name, value)
File "<path to mongoengine\base\fields.py">", line 144 , in __set__
  if instance._initiaised:
AttributeError: _initialised
```

What I am doing wrong here ?
My expectation is a new collection called student_db will get created in default mongo DB server running at "mongodb://127.0.0.1:2701" with a document having stdName field in it. 
I am referring to https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine#examples

Thanks

Comment: Can someone pls help me with an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `super().__init__()` after init:

```
def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwars):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwars)
    self.stdName = name
```